# Pydev, auto code format all files in an eclipse project

Tags: pydev, code-formatting

Please suggest a way to auto format all py files in an eclipse project using pydev auto code format. We're using the pydev code formatter to make our code consistent and would really like to get all files standardized.

Since we've enabled code formatting in pydev, every time a py file is touched by pydev, it gets changed at many places only due to code formatting cleanup. We'd like to do it across the project in one sweep.

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can apply code-formatting to all the files within a project/folder.

To do that, right-click a project/folder and select pydev > source format python files.

Comment: Thanks Fabio. Now if someone could only answer the question, how come I didn't think of looking there..duhhhh!!!